# Return exception object in java

Tags: java, object, exception, return

I wrote a custom exception as:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

  public CustomeException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

and try some tests as:

```
public static String test(String string) throws CustomException {
    if (string == null) {
      throw new CustomException("Empty String");
    }

    return string;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws CustomException {

    String testException = test(null);
    System.out.print(testException);
  }
```

When I run, it throws the exception. I wonder how can it returns the exception object instead of throwing an exception.

I mean the `testExpception` object will be `CustomExpception` when we input the string as null. Can we do it ?

Comment: It seems to me that you are heading down a dark path. Exceptions are for exceptional cases. If you want to return error information rather than raise an exception then you probably don't want an exception but rather some other value object to return information

Comment: Actually I use the custom exception in Spring Boot Web App. Whenever the rest controller meets my exception, it will throws the exception, I mean the rest controller will return the exception object (timestamp, errorCode, message, exceptionClass, path)

Answer (score 4):

That's for the try catch is designed for.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        String testException = test(null);
    }
    catch(CustomException e){// object e can be used for analysing the exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

Plus there is a typo in you exception constructor.it should be `CustomException` not `CustomeException`  and make the same change at other places as well

Comment: Thanks but can we ignore the try catch block ? I see some examples they just write as ```if (string == null)

Comment: Sorry for missing some things. I mean that they write as: ```
if (string == null) {
  throw new CustomException("Empty String");
}
```